# How set a field in an array as empty string if its null

Tags: mongodb, projection

If have a collection of levels. A sample document looks like below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d89ccf8c3c948ac48e449fc"),
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "option 1",
    "optionLevel" : [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "deparmentId" : null,
            "name" : "level 1"
        },
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "deparmentId" : null,
            "name" : "level 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

**How can I project a `documentId` inside `optionLevel` as empty string if its null?**

Comment: Please share a sample document.

Comment: optionSheet{ _id:1, name:"option 1", optionLevel:[{id:1,deparmentId:null,name:'level 1'},{id:2,deparmentId:null,name:'level 2'] }

Answer (score 0):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields:{
            "optionLevel":{
                $map:{
                    "input":"$optionLevel",
                    "as":"info",
                    "in":{
                        $mergeObjects:[
                            "$$info",
                            {
                                "deparmentId":{
                                    $ifNull:["$$info.deparmentId",""]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d89ccf8c3c948ac48e449fc"),
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "option 1",
    "optionLevel" : [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "deparmentId" : null,
            "name" : "level 1"
        },
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "deparmentId" : null,
            "name" : "level 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d89ccf8c3c948ac48e449fc"),
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "option 1",
    "optionLevel" : [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "deparmentId" : "",
            "name" : "level 1"
        },
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "deparmentId" : "",
            "name" : "level 2"
        }
    ]
}
```